# How can I remove multiple XML nodes at once?

Tags: c#, xml

I can remove an xml node using

```
 XmlNode node = newsItem.SelectSingleNode("XYZ");
 node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
```

But what if I want to remove multiple nodes at once, for example `XYZ,ABC,PQR`?

Is there any way to remove all of these nodes at once or do I have to remove them one by one?

**NOTE:** `XYZ,ABC,PQR` being at the same level(i.e they all have same parent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is inbuilt when using the `XmlDocument` API, but you could write a utility extension method, for example:

```
public static void Remove(this XmlNode node, string xpath)
{
    var nodes = node.SelectNodes(xpath);
    foreach (XmlNode match in nodes)
    {
        match.ParentNode.RemoveChild(match);
    }
}
```

then call:

```
newsItem.Remove("XYZ|ABC|PQR");
```

If you can change to the `XDocument` API, then things may be different.

Comment: +1 for the extension. but I thought there must be an inbuilt methord

Comment: May recommend changing it to return `XmlNode` like the [`RemoveChild`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.removechild.aspx) method does to keep similar and retain chaining when applicable.

Comment: @Brad IIRC, that would appear "out of place" with the `XmlNode` API, but: sure, you could do that. Actually, I'd be tempted to return the count of removed nodes...

Comment: Documentation for SelectNodes @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9.aspx says: The XmlNodeList object returned by this method will be valid while the underlying document remains unchanged. If the underlying document changes, unexpected results may be returned (no exception will be thrown). Can this be a problem when deleting xml nodes.

Answer (score 3):

think you could do something like that using linq to xml.

```
var listOfNodesToRemove = new[]{"XYZ", "ABC", "PQR"};

var document = XDocument.Load(<pathtoyourfile>);
document.Descendants
        .Where(m => listOfNodesToRemove.Contains(m.Name.ToString())
        .Nodes()
        .Remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

That would depend very much on the structure (nesting) etc.

But basically yes, for a handful of unrelated elements, select and remove them one at a time.

You could combine them to some extent:

```
List<string> RemoveNames = ...
var toBeRemoved = doc.Descendants().Where(d => RemoveNames.Contains(d.name));
foreach (var element in toBeRemoved.ToList()) ...
```

Comment: It will be same as removing them one by one

Comment: Yes, it will be. But in a loop that's not so bad.